# How I can upload a file using html input type "file" through ajax with web API model binder

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm using a MVC 5 web Api Controller, and I want my data coming through ajax with file to automatically bind?

Comment: you can append it to formdata.

Answer (score 0):

**You can append your uploaded file to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and send it via [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).**

---

**Here's a demo to get started:**

```js
window.onload = () => {

  document.querySelector('#myFile').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  
    // Just upload a single file, if you want multiple files then remove the [0]
    if (!event.target.files[0]) {
      alert('Please upload a file');
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myFile', event.target.files[0]);

    // Your REST API URL here
    const url = "";

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => alert('File uploaded successfully!'))
      .catch(err => {
        alert('Error while uploading file!');
      });
  });

};
```

```html
<input id="myFile" type="file" />
```

**After that just get the file from the current request in your API action method.**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadFile()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Do something with file now
        }
    }

    return Ok(new { message = "File uploaded successfully!" }); 
}
```